# Find all numbers $r$ for which the system of congruences is true

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations, congruences

Find all numbers $r$ for which the system of congruences
\begin{align*}
x &\equiv r \pmod{6}, \\
x &\equiv 9 \pmod{20}, \\
x &\equiv 4 \pmod{45}
\end{align*}has a solution.

---

Guess and check won't work, thanks in advance for giving a solution!

Comment: let $a = lcm(6,20,45) = 180$ then $x+a \equiv x \bmod 6,20$ and $45$, i.e. it has finitely many solutions in the interval $0 \le x < 180$ and all the others are obtained by adding $180k$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the second equation, since $x \equiv 9 \pmod{20}$, we know $x$ is odd. Then $r$ can be one of $1$, $3$, and $5$. From the third equation, $x \equiv 4 \pmod{45}$. We see that $x \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ (since $x = 45y+4$, for some integer $y$). Then we see that $r$ can only be $1$ (since if $x \equiv 3 \mod{6}$, it will have remainder $0$ when divided by $3$ and if $x \equiv 5 \mod{6}$, it will have remainder $2$ when divided by $3$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Prove first that a system of congruences
$$\begin{cases}x\equiv r\mod a\\x\equiv s\mod b\end{cases}$$
has a solution if and only if $\; r\equiv s\mod\gcd(a,b).$

Answer (score 1):

By the CRT, the constraint $x\equiv 9\pmod{20}$ is equivalent to the couple of constraints $x\equiv 4\pmod{5}$ and $x\equiv 1\pmod{4}$. In a similar way, the constraint $x\equiv 4\pmod{45}$ is equivalent to the couple of constraints $x\equiv 4\pmod{5}$ and $x\equiv 4\pmod{9}$. The last one implies $x\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ while $x\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ implies $x\equiv 1\pmod{2}$, hence the system has a solution iff $\color{red}{r\equiv 1\pmod{6}}$.